# react navigation modal buttons are un-clickable on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm testing my app on Android only to realize that it's impossible to close or click on any button inside my React Navigation modal on Android, when it works on iOS.

I can't find a reason for this and so here is my code:

The modal:

Modal.js

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => console.log('loook')}
      style={{
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.brandBlue,
        borderRadius: 50,
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: Colors.white }}>Click me</Text>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </View>
);
```

**Navigation.js**

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: CombineStack,
    Modal: Modal,
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
    transparentCard: true,
  }
)
```

Comment: Try importing the same component from `react-native-gesture-handler`. https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-touchables.html

Comment: Which component ?@Ziyo

Comment: TouchableWithoutFeedback

Comment: It does not work either.

Comment: Thanks @Ziyo, for me was the opposite. Buttons was not working inside modal on Android. Moving the import from gesture handler to react native fixed.